# Python: Get all equations and variables from calculation and turn them in symbols

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures

Hy guys I came with an idea, I have a big calculation written in python and right now i want to collect all variables and turn them in symbols. Same with equations. Trying to get variables and equations latex ready, and I really don't know how to collect all that variables and turn them in symbols.

Comment: I think you're looking for [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)

Comment: Yes, I am thinking about using Sympy, but it's really hard for me because I'm beginner how to get all variables, turn them into latex ready simbols (just simbols Fmax=12kN so simbol I need is F_max=symbols(F_{max}) and all equations that I have fill it with that simbols and print out.